# Need Solution for Full Calendar with list of events and link to specific event page

Tags: html, hyperlink, fullcalendar

I'm building my final project for my studies and I'm trying to make an event calendar that shows events in the calendar itself. I found a few solutions so I'm good with that part, I think.

Although, what I want to add is an option so that under my calendar there will be a list of all events for this month (it's a monthly calendar) and the list will match what's showing on the calendar itself.

When someone presses one of the events on the list it will take them to a specific page for the event, and there will be an option to have an open discussion about the event.

- Is that possible?
- Is it to complex for a beginner to do?
- What are my options?

Comment: Hello. Welcome here. Please note that there are few versions of FullCalendar, Please try using latest version and related methods and properties.

Comment: If you are using any web language to develop your project, please specify it in your question. It depends on your maturity with web technologies, like javascript and json. If you are aware of basics of it, your can easily create a small project with FullCalendar v4.

Comment: Please check this link: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick. Using this link you can provide url to specific events, either manually or using any web language.

Comment: Why bother with this second list? Users can click directly on the events in fullCalendar itself. Then you don't need to duplicate all the data or clutter up the screen with extra stuff. And there's less code to write to copy all the data. Just put a link in the "url" property for each event (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) and fullCalendar will automatically make it clickable. Or to do something a bit more sophisticated (e.g. open the links in a new tab) then use the `eventClick` callback as suggested by Khurram above.

Comment: As for the "open discussion about the event", that's a totally separate feature. Get the calendar clicking working first, and then worry about that. But it sounds like you need some kind of "comments" feature like on a blog. You can probably find ready-made or nearly-ready-made components which will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your replies,
well about the suggestions, making the calendar items clickable is nice, but that's not what I'm aiming for, I want them to be as I asked at the beginning, items appear in the calendar itself and as a list for that month under the calendar. also that might be important to add, the project is in Laravel. Adyson you said something about a ready-made or nearly-ready-made discussion component, is there anything in particular you know and like to recommend?

Comment: Check this out : https://github.com/connor11528/laravel-forum.. It may work for you

Comment: https://medium.com/employbl/build-an-online-forum-with-laravel-analyzing-the-application-part-3-9317a0f893b4